# How to run Python Script from Java Program

Tags: java, python

In my Java program I'm creating a Least Squares Approximation and exporting the coefficients, i.e. c1x+c2x^2+c3x^3..., to a text file that my Python script will read in and plot. However, I cannot even get a basic Hello World python file to run from my Java program. I've scoured the internet for answers and I've used all the tricks in the book. This is what I did: [methodsOneThroughTwo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVL0o.png) [methodsThreeThroughFour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8wN7.png) , and here is the output: [exceptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDTIg.png) .

I have the same python file, test.py, placed in two different locations, the first one being the directory of the java program (C:\Users\BScot\OneDrive\Desktop\Numerical Analysis\Lab2\test.py) and the second being in the directory of a python project, (C:\Users\BScot\OneDrive\Desktop\Numerical Analysis\Test\test.py), just to check if that would make a difference.

Some of the exceptions indicate that the file is found but it cannot run because it is not an executable; but when I add the python start command to the front of the file path it reads that it cannot find the file "python".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have space character in python script path. Try to quote it with \" \"

Also you should take a look at ProcessBuilder: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Comment: Just tried it with those quotes and the same errors still occur.